# Multiple Servers, externally, through single IP

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, nat

Let's say, I have a server which is directly connected to the internet (no firewall), and sits on 66.77.88.99 externally and internally sits on 192.168.0.1. I have my domain's records set up so that mydomain.com points to my external IP.

I also have another server, which sits on 192.168.0.2, but is only accessible internally, as I only have 1 external IP address. I have forwarded server2.mydomain.com to my external IP, but of course, it points to my first server.

Is there a way, to possibly route the traffic coming from server2.mydomain.com to the other server? I have been reading about this, but it's not very clear, using Microsoft ISA Server.

Thanks in advanced.

I would choose between the two servers with domains

> server 1 - server1.mydomain.com
>
> server 2 - server2.mydomain.com

Comment: try to use some kind of reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- reverse proxy (apache, squid...) facing your internet connexion, which will forward the requests to the corresponding webserver.
- Hosting the two websites on the same webserver and use two virtualhosts.

There is plenty of tutorials on the net which will explain to you how to do.